# How can I translate the javascript code to clojurescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, clojurescript, capacitor

I would like to use [capacitor/app](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app) to get the state (background or active) of my app on iOS.  My project is based on Clojurescript so it is necessary to translate the following javascript code to clojurescript one.

- Javascript

```js
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

App.addListener('appStateChange', ({ isActive }) => {
  console.log('App state changed. Is active?', isActive);
});
```

- translated clojurescript

```clj
(ns js.sample
  (:require ["@capacitor/app" :refer [App]]))

(.addListener App "appStateChange"
                  #((fn [isActive]
                      (js/console.log isActive))))
```

I suppose I would get `isActive` as `true` or `false`, but I constantly get an `undefined` output. What is wrong with my code? Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Remove the `#(...)` from around your `(fn ...)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! You are so great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(.addListener App "appStateChange"
                  (fn [^js event]
                    (js/console.log (.-isActive event))))
```

As cfrick's comment mentions, `#(...)` is not needed there. `#(...)` is basically just a shorthand for `(fn [...] ...)`, and you already have a function there.

In JS, `{isActive}` in a function's signature means that `isActive` will be assigned to the value of the `isActive` field of the object that was passed to the function.

`^js` in CLJS marks the name that follows it as one containing a JS object. It's necessary to make sure that things like `isActive` don't end up being renamed by the compiler during production build optimizations. It shouldn't be necessary in this case because `isActive` name is not something that you or some library invented but rather a name coming from JS API. But I still find it to be a good practice to delineate such things. (`^js` shouldn't be used with `goog` imports, however.)

Comment: Awesome, my problem solved perfectly. Thanks!!!

Comment: And, Thanks for you thorough explanation.